# Why sshpass does not get the same output with ssh?

Tags: ros, sshpass

I am trying to test a c/s application running on remote machine. The expected result is client calling for service, the service node will coredump with dumpfile generated.
When I ssh onto the remote machine, it works with coredump generated.
When I run the same cmd with sshpass, however, my service does't crash and no coredump file generated, but I get the same stdout info.
I am totally puzzed, sshpass differs with ssh not only password management?

Comment: sshpass is [broken](https://github.com/clarkwang/passh/blob/master/sshpass-broken.md) in some scenarios but without more details i have no idea what your issue is. please provide a [repro].

Comment: Thanks for reply. Detail info can not be provided. Simply speaking, I have a ros-service A running on remote linux, providing a service with callback. Client B also deployed on my remote linux, calling A for service with a struct request. The service A  will parse request with callback and send response. The callback has a known bug with specific req and will cause service restart with coredump. My issue is the service did not restart with coredump when I start client call with sshpass.

Comment: then you may try my [passh](https://github.com/clarkwang/passh) which is an sshpass alternative. or you can try other tools like [tag:expect] (for [tag:tcl]), [tag:pexpect] (for [tag:python]) or my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) (for shells).

Comment: Expect works fine, thanks a lot.

Comment: then i believe it's caused by sshpass' mishandling PTYs as shown in my https://github.com/clarkwang/passh/blob/master/sshpass-broken.md

Comment: Impressive work.